# How do i make top of img have border-radius, but not its bottom?

Tags: html, css

I have a little img card and i need to make its top corners have `border-radius` but when i apply it all corners become round

here's example

```css
.card-1{
  width: 200px;
  background: #5d5d5d;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="card-1">
  lorem ipsumm dolor sit amet 
  </div>
  <h1>
  Tittle
  </h1>
  <p>
  text here
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `border-top-right-radius` && `border-top-left-radius` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use separate border radiuses. Try on this in your css file

```
border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
```

Comment: Ooooh so you can do that in border-radius too, it worked, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  border: 3px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are special css properties to define border radius for each corner of a box. The css property `border-radius` is actually a shorthand for them. See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius fro details.

```css
div {
  width: 10em;
  height: 5em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.one {
  border-top-left-radius: 1em;
  border-top-right-radius: 1em;
}
.two {
  border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
body {
   display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="two">Two</div>
```